# Chat from one system to another in a terminal

Tags: networking, chat, text-user-interface

I would like send a chat message (like mail chat) between two systems, the systems are inter-connected proxy IP.

Comment: Have a look in https://askubuntu.com/questions/61995/chat-over-lan-from-linux-to-linux?newreg=48e69317ed184414ae8c3d89463199ed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `talk` or `ytalk`

More info:

- [Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_(software))
- [ytalk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/ytalk.1.html)

Alternatively:

You can use `netcat`,

On box1: `nc -l 3333`

On box2: `nc $IP 3333`, where $IP equals the local IP address of the first system.

Once you do this, in the same box (box2) , type something and press enter. Take a look on your other box.

You can also choose a different port and get it opened on the firewall.

Comment: Thank you.  I have gone through `netcat` working good. Actually I need like gmail chat, means here box1 is must be open then only box2 can go ahead. Directly con't proceed it. Do that possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Neuron was 15s faster :)

Since you don't state your specific OS or networking setup, it won't be easy to suggest anything. Have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61995/chat-over-lan-from-linux-to-linux) example of a "chat" using netcat.

Comment: Thanks @Lenniey, we are using CentOS and Fedora linux operating systems

Answer (score 0):

ychat for simple chat, but personally I'd be inclined to setup a (or just connect to an existing) IRC server